# What does the [] represent in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i've been developing in c# for 4 month and I still dont know what does the [] means in entity framework.

Here an example

```
[Column("mycolumn")]
public int Column {get;set;}
```

What is it functionality?

Its there another situation that i have to use it or just with entity framework?

Comment: [Attributes Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: it varies, depending on context. In your context you are adorning a property with an attribute. In other contexts you could be accessing an indexer or dimensioning an array.

Comment: Technically its a question about square brackets, which just happen to be generally (solely?) used for attributes.

Comment: Is that the school bell?

Comment: @MeirionHughes Indexers use square brackets as well

Comment: You just cannot asked a question that you dont know. Really cool

Comment: @DanielMann Ha! Can't believe I forgot that; sleep deprived due to newborn. :(

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets [ & ] mean a few different things in C#, but in this case they are saying that "Column" is an [Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288059%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  An attribute is basically design time information that you add to classes or properties for various reasons.  You can also make your own ;)

Comment: `design time information` ???

Comment: yeah - as in information you add to classes when you are designing them - not loaded in at runtime from some external source.  Sorry I don't know the proper word lol